# How to create report textbox aggregate expression in SQL Server Reporting?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SQL Server Reporting Services report that has a table with a ton of fields and then a textbox where I want to display the total weight. Now, the total weight is determined by a huge expression:

```
=Sum(Round(Code.ConvertWgt(Switch(Parameters!OrderLength.Value = 
"T",Fields!TotalTheorWeight.Value
    ,Parameters!OrderLength.Value = "C",Fields!TotalCutWeight.Value
    ,Parameters!OrderLength.Value = "P",Fields!TotalPayWeight.Value
    ,Parameters!OrderLength.Value = 
"OD",Switch(Fields!Calculate_Weight_Using_ID.Value = 
"T",Fields!TotalTheorWeight.Value                                    
,Fields!Calculate_Weight_Using_ID.Value = "C",Fields!TotalCutWeight.Value
,Fields!Calculate_Weight_Using_ID.Value = "P",Fields!TotalPayWeight.Value
)
),Switch(Parameters!WeightUnit.Value = "orderdflt"
,Fields!Default_Weight.Value,True,Parameters!WeightUnit.Value))
,CInt(IIF(Parameters!WeightPrecision.Value="uomdefault",Fields!Weight_Precision.Value,Parameters!WeightPrecision.Value))))
```

However, I see the following error when I try to preview the report:

> The Value expression for the text box ‘TotalWeight’ uses an aggregate expression without a scope.  A scope is required for all aggregates used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one dataset.

So I tried fixing it by changing it to:

```
=Sum(IiF(Round(Code.ConvertWgt(Switch(Parameters!OrderLength.Value = 
"T",Fields!TotalTheorWeight.Value
    ,Parameters!OrderLength.Value = "C",Fields!TotalCutWeight.Value
    ,Parameters!OrderLength.Value = "P",Fields!TotalPayWeight.Value
,Parameters!OrderLength.Value = "OD",Switch(Fields!Calculate_Weight_Using_ID.Value = "T",Fields!TotalTheorWeight.Value
                                            ,Fields!Calculate_Weight_Using_ID.Value = "C",Fields!TotalCutWeight.Value
                                            ,Fields!Calculate_Weight_Using_ID.Value = "P",Fields!TotalPayWeight.Value
    )
),Switch(Parameters!WeightUnit.Value = "orderdflt"
    ,Fields!Default_Weight.Value,True,Parameters!WeightUnit.Value))
    ,CInt(IIF(Parameters!WeightPrecision.Value="uomdefault",Fields!Weight_Precision.Value,Parameters!WeightPrecision.Value)))), "Order")
```

with Order being the name of the dataset that I want to use. But, then I see this error:

> The Value expression for the textrun ‘TotalWeight.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.

How do I go about fixing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIF is like IF in Excel - where =IF([some test],[if true do this],[if false do this]) ... so based off of the parentheses and commas you have, you're basically leaving out the [if true do this] and [if false do this] which is why you're getting that second error message about not having enough arguments.

As for the original error message, instead of using a text box, can you enter in a blank table with one row and one column and have it connected to the dataset?

Or have you thought about setting that value in a dataset - then setting that dataset to a parameter value, then using the parameter in your textbox?

You might also dig into this article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/built-in-collections-reportitems-collection-references-report-builder?view=sql-server-2017

Or this cross posted question here - I think this is what you need to do:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7d1c401c-e31d-4bc5-8c89-8684e63d3cd3/rsfieldreference-the-value-expression-for-the-textbox-8216allcustomcpi18217-refers-to-the?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: I didn't even think about just creating another table and connecting it to the dataset. that's what I ended up doing as it was the easiest solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So to address each expression, the first error is indicating that you need to specify a scope for the `SUM` aggregate.  This is as simple as adding the name of the dataset where the data is coming from inside the last parenthesis.  You'll need to add `..., "YourDatasetName")` so the following should work -- though such a complex expression is bound to have other issues.  For example, it's impossible for us to know if `ConvertWgt` is going to work correctly without an idea of what the parameters require.

```
=Sum(Round(
    Code.ConvertWgt(
    Switch(
        Parameters!OrderLength.Value = "T", Fields!TotalTheorWeight.Value
        ,Parameters!OrderLength.Value = "C",Fields!TotalCutWeight.Value
        ,Parameters!OrderLength.Value = "P",Fields!TotalPayWeight.Value
        ,Parameters!OrderLength.Value = "OD",
            Switch( Fields!Calculate_Weight_Using_ID.Value = "T",Fields!TotalTheorWeight.Value                                    
                    ,Fields!Calculate_Weight_Using_ID.Value = "C",Fields!TotalCutWeight.Value
                    ,Fields!Calculate_Weight_Using_ID.Value = "P",Fields!TotalPayWeight.Value
                  )
          ),Switch(Parameters!WeightUnit.Value = "orderdflt"
    ,Fields!Default_Weight.Value,True,Parameters!WeightUnit.Value))
    ,CInt(IIF(Parameters!WeightPrecision.Value="uomdefault",
              Fields!Weight_Precision.Value,
              Parameters!WeightPrecision.Value)))
    , "Order")
```

The second expression, unfortunately, is just a mess and I'm not sure it's salvageable.  You're trying to add an `IIF` but there's no conditional statement to evaluate from what I can tell.  You're basically just rounding a huge switch statement and there's no true or false part, nor can the expression evaluate in such a way that it will provide a true or false result.

I see you've already accepted an answer, but I was already halfway through this answer, so I'll post it regardless since the other answer didn't explain how to fix these expressions.